# CSS "sunken"/"inset" letter effect without using image

Tags: css, text

How is the "sunken" or "inset" effect applied to these letters in this menu?  I looked (briefly) with Firebug but can't find how they're doing it.  Works in FF, not in IE.

[image]

See http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/mybalsamiq for actual example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a [Text Shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/) with a color lighter than the background instead of darker, causing it to look like a bevel. (We've been trained to believe that the 'sunlight' on a computer screen generally comes from the upper left corner.)

The CSS rule shown when using the Developer Tools for Safari shows:

```
text-shadow: white 0px 1px 0px;
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know about sunlight.  Who needs the real stuff anyways.

Comment: Comes in handy to keep the vampires and zombies away while foraging for supplies

Answer (score 4):

That is most likely a `text-shadow`:

```
p {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

No version of IE in existence (not even IE9 beta) supports `text-shadow`.

Answer (score 1):

It's this:

`text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;`

Answer (score 0):

As I see, it's the color combination that create the effect. Just change the text to red color and the text is not inset anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick I discovered using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements:

http://dabblet.com/gist/1609945